# WideImage прозрачный холст

Tags: php

Как при помощи **WideImage** создать изображение размером x на y с прозрачный фоном, для того чтобы в дальнейшем на него наложить другие картинки, другими словами сделать холст для спрайтов.

Пожалуйста не скидывайте мне сервисы для создания спрайтов.

Answer (score 0):

Как через **WideImage** сделать так и не нашел, зато сделал через стандартный **GD**

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($newX, $newY);
imagealphablending($canvas, false);
imagesavealpha($canvas, true);
```

дальше если будут накладываться изображения то прозрачность будет сохранятся

```
imagecopyresampled($canvas, $newImage, $posX, $posY, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

- [imagealphablending](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagealphablending.php)
- [imagesavealpha](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagesavealpha.php)
- [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php)